# NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns NSManagedObject just deleted

Tags: iphone, ios

```
- (void)addPlace {
   //set up add controller
   PlacesAddViewController *addController = [[PlacesAddViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
   addController.delegate = self;
   // create new place and assign it to add controller
   Place *newPlace = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   addController.place = newPlace;

   // set up navigation controller
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
   [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

   // release controllers
   [navigationController release];
   [addController release];
}
```

The method insertNewObjectForEntityForName is returning a new instance of Place correctly when I try adding a place initially, but when I delete a place from the list then press "+" this method is called again and this time insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns the place that was just deleted.

Can anyone give me some ideas as to what is happening? I know this method returns an autoreleased object -- not sure if this has anything to do with it.

UPDATE: I think it's happening because right before the add view controller displays you can see the new object being inserted at the top of table view controller in the first row. When the add view controller is displayed the new object is indeed a new instance. Also, if I save this object it correctly replaces the row in the table view controller with the correct information. So maybe this has something to do with my table view below. Ahhh, I just figured it out and answered my own question. My cellForRowAtIndexPath was using a reused cell and the information was displaying the latest cell deleted. I've since fixed this. Thanks though for the reassurance it wasn't the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be happening given the code above. Why do you think that is what's happening? Add NSLog statements to output properties of `newPlace` after it has been inserted and before you present the `navigationController` to verify this. I would also do some logging in `addController`. Whatever is going on, the problem is likely there. What is the @property definition for the `place` property in `addController`? Add some more code and I'll try to help more.